# How to join rows and cols in google spread sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Here are 4 cells like this.

```
  A B
1 a b
2 c d
```

I want to join them by , and ¥n.

```
C1 => a,b¥nc,d
```

How can I do this with functions google spread sheets have and without javascript? https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: I don't know whether it's written in spread sheets, but in python if there is  `cells = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]`, I can join nested lists like this `"\n".join([",".join(row) for row in cells]) `.  moreover I want to expand the 2 * 2 cells to m * n array in fact . And I want to use only the join function without a substitute function. Unfortunately I don't know how to use the join of spread sheets above.

Answer (score 2):

See if something like this works:

```
=ArrayFormula(Substitute(JOIN("¥n", query(trim(transpose(A1:B2)),,rows(A1:A2)))," ", ", "))
```

- The query() creates an output of two cells where the values of each row are joined, separated with a space. (note the use of the optional headers argument, set to the number of rows.
- Then these two cells are joined with "¥n".
- Finally the spaces are substituted with a comma.

Comment: Thanks! but if A1 contains a space for example, the result string has an unnecessary comma.

Comment: While this answer may fix the problem, it will be far more useful to future readers if you provide an explanation as to why this is the best approach.  Code-only answers tend to be only minimally helpful on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TobySpeight. I do understand. Not any unwillingness from my part, but mostly due to a lack of time. Don't think I ever refused to explain when asked to though. Also I only tried to provide a possible solution.. I would not dare to think mine is the 'best approach'. Anyway.. hope my explanation makes sense. Cheers, JP.

Comment: @hiroyuki: I updated my answer to deal with extra spaces.  I added the trim() funciton to the formula. The transpose() is added because the query needs to join per row (not per column). Hope that helps ?

Comment: @JPV thanks again! your answer is almost the best, but if A1 is "a a", although I know it works if A1 is " a ", it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share some more 'realistic' example AND the expected outcome ? I'll be glad to have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry to explain little. I wrote what I want above. If I take more examples, `=join("¥n", join(",", RANGE))` => `cell11,cell12,...,cell1M¥ncell21,cell22,...,cell2M¥n...¥n...,cellNM`